# SQL Server Automatic Rounding?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

I am very confused by the following results:

```
PRINT 3.1415926535897931 /180
```

Console result = 0.01745329251994329500

```
DECLARE @whatTheHell float(53)
SET @whatTheHell  = 3.1415926535897931/180
PRINT @whatTheHell
```

Console result = 0.0174533

I don't understand because referring to this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Sql Server Float should be equivalent to c# double.
But when I compute this in c#:

```
double hellYeah = 3.1415926535897931 /180;
```

I get 0.017453292519943295...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're getting confused by the fact that `PRINT` implicitly converts numeric to character with the default setting for the `STR` function -- a length of 10 (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527(SQL.90).aspx)). Try `PRINT STR(@wth, 20, 16)` and you might be happier.

Comment: More likely "Data type precedence" and evaluation of constants etc

Answer (score 4):

Divide is not rounding.  PRINT is rounding.

```
DECLARE
  @var1 float,
  @var2 float,
  @var3 float

SET @var1 = 3.1415926535897931
SET @var2 = 180

SET @var3 = @var1 / @var2
SELECT @var1/@var2 as Computed, @var3 as FromVariable

PRINT @var1/@var2
PRINT @var3
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the "FLOAT" type just has a limit on precision. Books Online says with FLOAT(53) you should get up to 15 digits of precision - not sure if there's an inherent limitation whether those digits are before or after the decimal separator.

Try using decimal instead:

```
DECLARE @whatTheHell2 decimal(18,16)
SET @whatTheHell2  = 3.1415926535897931/180
PRINT @whatTheHell2
```

Gives me the result:

```
0.0174532925199433
```

Marc

Comment: But when you read this msdn documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

You see that sql Float precision is equivalent to c# double precision.

Or when I compute this with c#:

double pipo = 3.1415926535897931 /180;

I get : 0.017453292519943295

???

Comment: I know - that's what puzzled me too - see the other answers for additional info. Seems SQL server assumes some kind of default precision for FLOAT - use NUMERIC or DECIMAL instead with explicit precision settings

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL Server 2005 Books Online [Data Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530(SQL.90).aspx#_decimal) topic:

> In Transact-SQL statements, a constant
>   with a decimal point is automatically
>   converted into a numeric data value,
>   using the minimum precision and scale
>   necessary. For example, the constant
>   12.345 is converted into a numeric value with a precision of 5 and a
>   scale of 3.

So the following is more representative of what SQL Server is doing implicitly:

```
DECLARE @whatTheHell NUMERIC(21, 20)
SET @whatTheHell = 3.1415926535897931 / 180
PRINT @whatTheHell
```

Comment: referring to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx, float(53) should have a precision of 15 digits. Just like c# double: the c# result has indeed 15 digits. So I really don't understand why I end up with a precision of 6 digits with a float(53)...

Answer (score 1):

`PRINT 3.1415926535897931 /180` is being evaluated as decimal.

Float only resolves to 15 significant figures. You have 17 so it can't be float. The 180 becomes decimal through implicit conversion because of [datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) and the output scale and precision [is based on these rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx)

The output 0.01745329251994329500 has 17 sig figs too. It must be decimal.

Now, `SET @whatTheHell  = 3.1415926535897931/180`. The float conversion takes place as part of the assignment operator. Before that it is also decimal on the right hand side. Float is approximate, and it's rounding.

In c# it's all doubles because you don't have *fixed* point (unless you tell the compiler?)

Related questions:

[Choosing the appropriate precision for decimal(x,y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806126/choosing-the-appropriate-precision-for-decimalx-y)

[In SQL how can I convert a money datatype to a decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638290/in-sql-how-can-i-convert-a-money-datatype-to-a-decimal)

[SQL Server, where clauses comparisons with different types & default casting behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831150/sql-server-where-clauses-comparisons-with-different-types-default-casting-beha)

Answer (score 0):

When you say that SQL float maps to C# double, I think you are assuming that the SQL float byte size is the same as the C# double byte size.

I would say that the C# double is the only floating point data type big enough, in C#, to store the SQL float.

Example:

C# Double = 8 Bytes
Sql Float = 4 bytes

The easy fix for your problem is to use decimal or numeric in your SQL

Comment: in my case it's a float(n) with (n = 53) > 24, so it has a 8 bytes precision, just like a c# double. (cf. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)